# Liberar Conexão Externa MySQL

Tags: mysql

Recentemente fiz a configuração de um servidor MySQL com espelhamento.
Seguindo este procedimento: https://hostpresto.com/community/tutorials/how-to-setup-mysql-master-master-replication-on-ubuntu-16-04/

O comando para liberar acesso já foi executado:

> GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'Qwerty@123';

Contudo a linha em: `$ sudo nano /etc/mysql/my.cnf`

> bind-address = 127.0.0.1

Está impedindo conexões esternas!

Como faço para permitir conexões externas uma vez que estou fazendo espelhamento com esse procedimento?

Answer (score 1):

Mude o bind-address para 0.0.0.0, que significa "todas as interfaces de rede". O valor 127.0.0.1 se refere a interface de rede loopback, que permite apenas conexão local, no próprio servidor.

Comment: Não foi isso que eu perguntei amigo! Infelizmente não me serve sua resposta. O Problema é que quando eu configura a linha 'bind-address = 192.168.0.1' com um determinado IP somente este mesmo ip poderá acessá-lo exteriormente.

Comment: bind-address é o endereço da interface, não é o endereço do IP que pode acessar o servidor.